# java XMLUtils.outputDOM output is empty

Tags: java, xml

Cant figure out why XMLUtils.outputDOM is not outputing anything

```
import org.apache.xml.security.utils.XMLUtils;

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader("<EDoc></EDoc>"));
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
System.out.println(root);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("out_xs.xml");
XMLUtils.outputDOM(root, os, true);
System.out.println(XMLUtils.getFullTextChildrenFromElement(root));
```

Output is:

```
[EDoc: null]
(empty string)
```

out_xs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I can get the root element OK, but file is generated with xml definition only as `true` is provided. What is going on? I am using same function in other place where it works after library uses Document, so I suspect `Document` should be notified to commit changes? Cant find any information using search

Comment: Did you close the `OutputStream`?

Comment: @Kayaman added os.close() after outputDOM, nothing changed

Comment: I'm confused. Your question seems to be about the `out_xs.xml` file not getting XML, but you don't show us what is actually in the file. Instead you show us that `getFullTextChildrenFromElement(root)` returns an empty string, which has nothing whatsoever to do with `outputDOM(root, os, true)`, and blank output is expected, since there are no text nodes in the XML, so not sure why that code is even there, except it is confusing the issue. Please clean up the question, to clarify it.

Comment: @Andreas updated question and added out_xs.xml contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is a bit confusing / unclear. I ran the code provided and the xml file generated "out_xs.xml" contains the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EDoc></EDoc>
```

... which is correct according to the code block you've specified.

I did have to make a slight change to your code though, had to add the line `Init.init();` just above `XMLUtils.outputDOM(root, os, true);`. Otherwise I kept getting the exception *org.apache.xml.security.c14n.InvalidCanonicalizerException: You must initialize the xml-security library correctly before you use it*

Maybe check your dependency versions, I used the following in Gradle:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-security/xmlsec
compile group: 'xml-security', name: 'xmlsec', version: '1.3.0'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging
compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.1.1'
```